# Preview Crashed when I get data from api

Tags: swift, swiftui, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data from API according to a tutorial on YouTube and I does exactly as the video but the preview somehow crashed. But when I commented out the Api().getPosts , the preview is able to resume again. If that line of code is wrong how can I write it instead?

User Interface code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var posts: [Post] = []
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(posts) { post in
                Text(post.title)
            }
                .onAppear{
                    Api().getPosts { (posts) in
                        self.posts = posts
                    }
                }
        }//:VSTACK

    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Api Service code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Post: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var body: String
}

class Api {
    func getPosts(completion: @escaping([Post]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts") else { return
            print("Something occured!")
        }
        
        //CALL
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            let posts = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(posts)
            }
            
            print(posts)
        }//:URLSESSION
        .resume()
    }
}
```

[image: Preview Crashed]

Comment: If the tutorial doesn’t suggest any error handling look for a better tutorial. At least wrap the decoding line in a `do - catch` block to get a potential decoding error, actually **the** decoding error.

Comment: More long term solution , do not create an instance of you Api type inside onAppear, either have it as `shared` type or inject an instance into your view by having it as a property. If you do this then you can either have a variant of `shared` named `preview` that returns a mocked object or you can inject a mock object for your preview.

Answer (score 2):

use this code for your `Post` model:

```
struct Post: Codable, Identifiable {
   // let id = UUID()  // <-- or this
    var id: Int        // <-- here
    var title: String
    var body: String
}
```

Comment: Solved! But is the previous one not working

Comment: well previously you had `var id = UUID()`, that is `id` of type `UUID`, but it is in reality of type `Int`. When you use `let id = UUID()`, then Xcode will tell you that it will not be decoded because it is a let with a given value. If this solves your question, could you mark the answer as correct (with the tick mark)